# data binding is not working.module name is not pass to the html page

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

data binding is not working.
module name is not displayed to my application.module name is not pass to the html page.module name can view in the console.but not in the app display.
html code

```
<ion-view  ng-controller="coursedetailctrl as vm">
    <ion-content class="has-header">
 <ion-list>
        <div class="card">
            <ion-item>
                  {{modulename}}

            </ion-item> 
        </div>  
</ion-list>
<ion-infinite-scroll
  icon="ion-loading-c"
  on-infinite="loadMoreData()">
</ion-infinite-scroll>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

js page

```
 (function(){

var aapp = angular.module('leadGen');


aapp.controller('coursedetailctrl', function($state, $scope, ContentService, $stateParams ){   
     var dat;
var vm=this;
 ContentService.getCourses($stateParams.cid).then(function(data) {

                        var myparam= $stateParams.cid;
                          dat=data;

                            $scope.coursedetail=dat;      
                    }, this);
$scope.selectModule= function(id){

   for(var j=0;j<dat.Modules.length;j++)
   {
     if(id==dat.Modules[j].id){
console.log(dat.Modules[j].name);
$scope.modulename=dat.Modules[j].name;
$state.go('module', {mid: id});

     }
   }
 console.log(id); 
}
});
}());
```

modulename is not displayed.

Comment: Is this is the first time defined or already defined somewhere else `var aapp = angular.module('leadGen');
`?

Comment: What is the output of console.log($scope.modulename) ?

Comment: output of console.log is modulenames like module1.

Comment: data is getting from an api.i need module names from api.console print the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (as you have defined your controller as "vm"):

```
<ion-view  ng-controller="coursedetailctrl as vm">
    <ion-content class="has-header">
 <ion-list>
        <div class="card">
            <ion-item>
                  **{{vm.modulename}}**

            </ion-item> 
        </div>  
</ion-list>
<ion-infinite-scroll
  icon="ion-loading-c"
  on-infinite="loadMoreData()">
</ion-infinite-scroll>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

And your js (no need to use "$scope.module"):

```
(function(){

var aapp = angular.module('leadGen');


aapp.controller('coursedetailctrl', function($state, $scope, ContentService, $stateParams ){   
     var dat;
var vm=this;
 ContentService.getCourses($stateParams.cid).then(function(data) {

                        var myparam= $stateParams.cid;
                          dat=data;

                            vm.coursedetail=dat;      
                    }, this);
vm.selectModule= function(id){

   for(var j=0;j<dat.Modules.length;j++)
   {
     if(id==dat.Modules[j].id){
console.log(dat.Modules[j].name);
**vm.modulename=dat.Modules[j].name;**
$state.go('module', {mid: id});

     }
   }
 console.log(id); 
}
});
}());
```

And your ng-repeat and function call:

```
<ion-list> <div class="card"> <ion-item ng-repeat="module in vm.coursedetail.Modules" ng-click="vm.selectModule(module.id)"> {{vm.module.name}} <div> {{vm.module.description}} </div> </ion-item> </div> </ion-list>
```

Comment: Also from where you are calling this function $scope.selectModule ?

Comment: `
<ion-list>
        <div class="card">
            <ion-item ng-repeat="module in coursedetail.Modules"  ng-click="selectModule(module.id)">
                  {{module.name}}
                  <div>
                  {{module.description}}
                  </div>
            </ion-item> 
        </div>  
</ion-list>`

Comment: Refer my attached answer: within your html always refer vm to access any of the variable of functions, within you controller define all your variables with vm. instead of $scope. (including you fucntions)

Answer (score 0):

This look like closure issue.
If you are using ECMA6 then write loop in this way.

```
for(let j=0;j<dat.Modules.length;j++)
   {
      if(id==dat.Modules[j].id){
        console.log(dat.Modules[j].name);
        $scope.modulename=dat.Modules[j].name;
        $state.go('module', {mid: id});
      }
   }
```

OR you can use like this one

```
(function(index){
   $scope.modulename=dat.Modules[index].name;
})(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

> When you are doing Controller aliasing (As you done in your code). you
>   have to use alias name with model in view. To run your code try this

```
<ion-view  ng-controller="coursedetailctrl as vm">
    <ion-content class="has-header">
 <ion-list>
        <div class="card">
            <ion-item>
                  {{vm.modulename}}

            </ion-item> 
        </div>  
</ion-list>
<ion-infinite-scroll
  icon="ion-loading-c"
  on-infinite="loadMoreData()">
</ion-infinite-scroll>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and in controller defination tou can use `this` keyword to refer controller in your case

```
 var vm=this;
```

use `vm` to bind modulename

```
(function(){

var aapp = angular.module('leadGen');


aapp.controller('coursedetailctrl', function($state, $scope, ContentService, $stateParams ){   
     var dat;
var vm=this;
 ContentService.getCourses($stateParams.cid).then(function(data) {

                        var myparam= $stateParams.cid;
                          dat=data;

                            $scope.coursedetail=dat;      
                    }, this);
$scope.selectModule= function(id){

   for(var j=0;j<dat.Modules.length;j++)
   {
     if(id==dat.Modules[j].id){
console.log(dat.Modules[j].name);
vm.modulename=dat.Modules[j].name;
$state.go('module', {mid: id});

     }
   }
 console.log(id); 
}
});
}());
```

Hope it helps

Comment: is any problem with $state.go statement